# jQuery slider opacity error only on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a custom built slider on a Magento site. It's responsive and have custom touch behaviour on it. The behaviour should be the following:

1. Three images slider, the middle one should have opacity 1.0, the rest just 0.15
2. On smaller resolutions, only show 2 images. The one on the right should have 1.0 the left image should have 0.15 opacity
3. On mobile, show 1 image. The current shown image should have 1.0 opacity.

I made it work with CSS/jQuery mix.

HTML

```
<ul class="more-views">
<li><a href="someURL"><img src=..... /></li>
<li class="active"><a href="someURL"><img src=..... /></li>
<li><a href="someURL"><img src=..... /></li>
<li><a href="someURL"><img src=..... /></li>
<li><a href="someURL"><img src=..... /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS
.more-views ul li { opacity: .15; } 
.more-views ul li.active { opacity: 1.0; }

JAVASCRIPT
is long, you might want to inspect element. But the idea is the following. When you click NEXT arrow, the first element of the list is cloned, appended to the back of the  and  destroyed from the first position. Later on the active class is removed and added to the second `<li>` in the list. Something like this

```
<ul>
<li class="elem1"></li>
<li class="elem2 active"></li>
<li class="elem3"></li>
<li class="elem4"></li>
</ul>
```

STEP 1

```
<ul>
<li class="elem1"></li>
<li class="elem2 active"></li>
<li class="elem3"></li>
<li class="elem4"></li>
<li class="elem1"></li>
</ul>
```

STEP 2

```
<ul>
<li class="elem2 active"></li>
<li class="elem3"></li>
<li class="elem4"></li>
<li class="elem1"></li>
</ul>
```

STEP 3

```
<ul>
<li class="elem2"></li>
<li class="elem3 active"></li>
<li class="elem4"></li>
<li class="elem1"></li>
</ul>
```

Current small issue is the following:
1. If you click the right arrow (next arrow) one time, the first element in the list keeps the opacity as 1.0 (only on Chrome).
2. If you inspect the element is says it has an opacity of 0.15
3. If you resize the browser you'll see that the opacity is set to .15 again
4. If you enable/disable the opacity in Firebug it works like it should.
5. If you click 2 times on the next arrow the opacity error disappears.

You can see the live example here:
http://www.mackage.com/ca/en/jeffrey-black-leather-jacket

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following rule declaration from line 298 of site.css seemed to fix the issue.

```
.product-view .product-img-box .more-views ul li:nth-child(2),
```

Chrome must be getting confused calculating the nth child when you are removing the left most (top of the list) element. It must be calculating the nth-child before removing the DOM element.

Also, with the active class, it looks like you shouldn't need the nth-child rule.